# How can I paginate a UTF-8 file and see the right characters?

Tags: cat, unicode, less

If I use cat on a file containing UTF-8, it displays properly:

```
% cat /tmp/sample
<concept code="endangeredLanguage">
  <description value="The language is endangered at the given date"@en/>
  <description value="La lengua está en vías de extinción en la fecha dada"@es/>
  <description value="O idioma está em vias de extinção na data indicada"@pt/>
  <description value="La langue est menacée à la date indiquée"@fr/>
  <description value="ある時点でその言語は絶滅寸前である"@ja/>
  <description value="De taal is bedreigd met uitsterven op de gegeven datum"@nl/>
</concept>
```

But if I use "less", the non-ASCII characters are escaped:

```
% less /tmp/sample
<concept code="endangeredLanguage">
  <description value="The language is endangered at the given date"@en/>
  <description value="La lengua est<C3><A1> en v<C3><AD>as de extinci<C3><B3>n en la fecha dada"@es/>
  <description value="O idioma est<C3><A1> em vias de extin<C3><A7><C3><A3>o na data indicada"@pt/>
  <description value="La langue est menac<C3><A9>e <C3><A0> la date indiqu<C3><A9>e"@fr/>
  <description value="<E3><81><82><E3><82><8B><E6><99><82><E7><82><B9><E3><81><A7><E3><81><9D><E3><81><AE><E8><A8><80><E8><AA><9E><E3><81><AF><E7><B5><B6><E6><BB><85><E5><AF><B8><E5><89><8D><E3><81><A7><E3><81><82><E3><82><8B>"@ja/>
  <description value="De taal is bedreigd met uitsterven op de gegeven datum"@nl/>
</concept>
```

presumably because less is treated them as though they were binary. How can I paginate the output, but still see the proper characters?

Comment: What does `env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 less /tmp/sample` show?

Comment: I second @thrig - with UTF-8 locale set, my `less` shows the correct Unicode characters. (`less 481 (PCRE regular expressions)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the `less` FAQ *[Can less display non-English language characters?](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#intl)*

> Less has two ways to display non-English characters. If your system uses a non-ASCII single-byte character set, you should set up your system with the correct "locale" settings. If your system does not support setlocale, you can set the `LESSCHARSET` or `LESSCHARDEF` environment variable to tell less what language you are using. See the section "NATIONAL CHARACTER SETS" in the man page for details.
>
> If your system supports the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode for non-ASCII text, as many modern systems do, you should either set your locale to something that includes the  "UTF-8" or "UTF8" (either uppercase or lowercase is ok), or set `LESSCHARSET` to "utf-8".

Answer (score 2):

Add the following variable to your environment:

```
export LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```